# My onTouchListener doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, spinner

Sorry for my bad english but'im italian. I've a spinner and I want when it's disabled, a toast shows. But i can't make it work! I'm using another onTouchListener and it works good, but this listener doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
private void buildSpinnerOrdinata(String element) {
    spinnerOrdinata=null;
    spinnerOrdinataArray=new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerOrdinataArrayAdapter=null;
    try {
        if(element.equals(""))
            spinnerOrdinataArray.add("Seleziona un'ordinata");
        else
            spinnerOrdinataArray=databaseHelper.getOrdinataCpmAnalysis(element);

        spinnerOrdinata = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerOrdinata);
        if(addingRecord==true){
            spinnerOrdinataArray.add(0, "Seleziona un'ordinata");
        }
        spinnerOrdinataArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner, spinnerOrdinataArray);
        spinnerOrdinataArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerOrdinata.setAdapter(spinnerOrdinataArrayAdapter);
        if(addingRecord==true){
            spinnerOrdinata.setOnTouchListener(null);
            spinnerOrdinata.setOnTouchListener(SpinnerOrdinataOnTouch);
        }
        if(tabellaGiaScelta==false&&addingRecord==true){
            spinnerOrdinata.setOnTouchListener(null);
            spinnerOrdinata.setEnabled(false);
            spinnerOrdinata.setOnTouchListener(disabledSpinnerOnTouch);
        }
        else{
            spinnerOrdinata.setEnabled(true);
            spinnerOrdinata.setOnTouchListener(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

and this is my listener:

```
private View.OnTouchListener disabledSpinnerOnTouch=new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non è possibile selezionare questo campo, è disabilitato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Spinner spinnerOr=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerOrdinata);
                spinnerOr.performClick();
            }
            return true;
        }
};
```

where is the mistake? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you disabled the spinner by calling setEnabled(false). After that it doesn't listen to touch events.

I would extend Spinner class and make my own implementation with only one method that would be the overridden PeformClick method, where you would call parent version if you want to display Spinner items, or you would not call the parent version but rather your toast telling your user that it is disabled

This is how it can be done.

```
public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner{

private boolean mEnabled;
private final Toast mDisabledToast;

public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mDisabledToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Non è possibile selezionare questo campo, è disabilitato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    if(mEnabled)
        return super.performClick();
    else {
        mDisabledToast.show();
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled){
    mEnabled = enabled;
}
```

}

Don't forget to use newly created CustomSpinner class in you layout xml instead of base Spinner class. You can do it like this:

```
        <com.example.CustomSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: so how can i make it work? i really need a toast shows when i ckick on a disabled spinner

Comment: I don't know of any easy way out. I would extend Spinner class and make my own implementation with only one method that would be the overridden PeformClick method, where you would call parent version if you want to display Spinner items, or you would not call the parent version but rather your toast telling your user that it is disabled

Comment: It doesn't work. when i extend my spinner with this class, i see this error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to ComboElement.CustomSpinner. I dont know why it doesnt work because your class extends spinner so, where is the problem?? I made another class extends dialog and i overrided his methods and it works. But i've lot of troubles with this spinners >.<

Comment: You have to reference your newly created custom spinner in xml. I mean use CustomSpinner class in xml instead of Spinner.

Comment: Have you provided right path to the custom class? I mean com.example.CustomSpinner has to be full path to your class. It has to work, so check if the path provided is ok.

Comment: My bad. I have provided wrong constructor. I have edited my answer. Make the changes and it will work. I have just tested.

Comment: Only one little detail.. The spinners have lost their disabled look.. They're not longer grey.

Comment: That is the drawable used for disabled spinner, that is not touchable. You on the other hand need touchable spinner, that will show toast when the spinner is "disabled".

I don't know of any nice way how to have both things. Because you need different drawable that is used throughout Android versions. The only possibility would be to use your own drawable background for spinner states.